# Setting the text-effect of a TextArea in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Simple question, that I have surprisingly difficult time to find a clear answer for:

How can I change the text-effect of a TextArea (or TextField).

Setting the effect of TextArea naturally affects the boundaries of the area only.

Comment: You can't. Look into [`Text`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html) and [`TextFlow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html). Some examples [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/text/jfxpub-text.htm).

Comment: That's a bit unfortunate. Yep, I knew about Text & TextFlow, but I really need my text to be selectable & editable.

Comment: What is a "text-effect" required in your context?  What exactly is the effect you are trying to achieve?  What code did you use for "Setting the effect of TextArea"?  Are you trying to achieve multiple or mixed effects within a single text area?

Comment: Well, I was thinking generally of the `Effect`-class, and applying those directly into the text of `TextArea`, but I'm actually after just a simple drop shadow. Perhaps it is achieavable in other ways?